# Application_MapRequestHandler is occasionally really slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

Occasionally we're seeing a page which usually takes 30ms, take over 5000ms and mostly all of that time is spent somewhere between the asp.net pipeline steps Application_PostResolveRequestCache and Application_MapRequestHandler. We're using a mix of webform/mvc3 in iis 7, but this issue only seems to happen to old school webform pages (ashx, asmx,aspx). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be break on PostResolveRequestCache and see what is going on. It may be that the compression in cache is causing issues.